# Yii: CMenu items for different module

Tags: yii, cmenu

I'd like to make a menu in Layout which the items are linked to other different module.

e.g: 
Item "Product" linked to an action in Product Module, item "Service" linked to an action in Service Module.

It won't work when I set the `'url'=>('product/<controllerID>/<actionID>')` and `'url'=>('service/<controllerID>/<actionID>')` because once we're in Product module and click the menu "Service", the URL become

`index.php?r=product/service/<controllerID>/<actionID>`

instead of

```
index.php?r=service/<controllerID>/<actionID>
```

and it will be 404 error. (for sure, because the Service Module isn't inside Product Module but the URL makes it looks like that).

Any solution for this?

Comment: can you show your lines for the cmenu widget?

Comment: I've shown the code for 'url' associated array. I think that's the most important code part of this problem.

Comment: i just wanted to make sure there aren't any typos, anyway, i think i have a solution, lemme put it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [`createUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail) documentation :

> the URL route. This should be in the format of 'ControllerID/ActionID'. If the ControllerID is not present, the current controller ID will be prefixed to the route. If the route is empty, it is assumed to be the current action. If the controller belongs to a module, the module ID will be prefixed to the route. (**If you do not want the module ID prefix, the route should start with a slash '/'.**)

That last line tells us everything. Best thing to do for you is start all the routes with a `/` :

```
'url'=>array('/<moduleID>/<controllerID>/<actionID>')
```

Comment: did you check the solution? did it not work? you want some clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
'url'=>$this->createUrl('/<moduleId>/<controllerID>/<actionID>')
```

Comment: nope, it didn't work.. So far I know, every value associated with 'url' in CMenu will be passed to CHtml::normalizeUrl then passed to CController::createUrl(). So there will be double-nested createUrl(), means 404 error.